# Unable to dequeue table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic-tables

I am attempting to create a dynamic table in my iOS application but keep getting the infamous message:

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CEMBurialCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier".

Below is my code that isn't working.

Below is some data in the maincontroller.

```
#import "CEMBurialCell.h"    // The custom cell I want to use in the tableView

@interface CEMMainViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *deathstoday;
}
```

This is some code in the `viewWillAppear:` method.

```
deathstoday = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 370, 300, 50)];
deathstoday.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
deathstoday.delegate = self;
deathstoday.dataSource = self;
deathstoday.scrollEnabled = YES;    
[self.view addSubview:deathstoday];    
[self fetchfeed];   // This populates the array for the tableview
```

This is code in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CEMBurialCell" bundle:nil];    
[deathstoday registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CEMBurialCell"];
```

This is where I get the error:

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CEMBurialCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CEMBurialCell *cell = [tableView
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CEMBurialCell"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I initialized the `CEMBurialCell` in the `viewDidLoad` method so why am I getting this error? I got this routine to work in a program that has an init of:

```
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]; // in program that does work
```

whereas the program that doesn't work has an init of

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];   // in program that doesn't work
```

So the above two line lines are the main differences in the two programs.  I used a custom cell rather than a `UITableView` cell because I need an actionBlock in my cell. So why is the second program getting the error on my custom cell? The same custom cell `CEMBurialCell` works in the other program. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple. In `viewDidLoad`, `deathstoday` is `nil` so you don't actually register the nib.

Why do you wait until `viewWillAppear:` to create the table view? You should create the table view in `viewDidLoad` before your call to `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Just be sure to base the table view's frame on `self.view.bounds` so the `autoresizingMask` works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I moved the table creation to viewDidLoad and it worked.  I swore that I used the same code as in the program that worked but apparently not.  Thanks again.